# Cannot read the row of the gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I am trying to read a gridview row. Here is my code:

```
 protected void allStudents_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Approval")
    {
        // *** Retreive the DataGridRow
        int row = -1;
        int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out row);

        GridViewRow gdrow = allStudents.Rows[row];

        // *** Get the underlying data item - in this case a DataRow
        DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.allStudents.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];

        // *** Retrieve our context
        string courseCode = dr["CourseCode"].ToString();
        string courseNumber = dr["CourseNumber"].ToString();
        string term = dr["Term"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Userfunctions.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RegisterTable.StudentID, StudentTable.Name, StudentTable.Surname FROM RegisterTable JOIN StudentTable ON RegisterTable.StudentID = StudentTable.ID WHERE RegisterTable.CourseCode = @courseCode AND RegisterTable.Term = @term AND RegisterTable.CourseNumber = @courseNumber", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseCode", courseCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseNumber", courseNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        transcript.DataSource = dt;
        transcript.DataBind();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Students who are registered to " + courseCode + " " + courseNumber + " are listed below:";
    }
}
```

But at the line starting with

```
DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.allStudents.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];
```

i get an error saying that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Can anyone tell the problem here?

Note: allStudents is the ID of my gridview

Thanks

Comment: But a breakpoint on the row in question.  Which object is null?  allStudents? DataSource?

Comment: please show your gridviews markup too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means of the references in the line is `null`. That is, you're trying to fetch data from an object, but there is no instantiated object there.

Recommendation: insert a breakpoint at that line. Debug the code. Then, while debugging and on that line, pass the mouse cursor over every name in the line. The debugger will give you rich, detailed information about each and every variable. Once you find which one is null (could be either allStudents or DataSource), you'll be on the right track to solve your problem.

You have to find out whatever is triggering the error for being `null`, then making sure it's not `null` when you get to that point in your code.